# Firebase push notifications with cordova foreground and background n

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on Cordova with react Project. I have set up google firebase google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist for android and ios. I am using the below package for firebase notifications setup.

https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

```
FCM.requestPushPermission({
    ios9Support: {
        timeout: 10, // How long it will wait for a decision from the user before returning `false`
        interval: 0.3, // How long between each permission verification
    },
}).then((wasPermissionGiven) => {
    console.log(wasPermissionGiven);
    alert(JSON.stringify(wasPermissionGiven));
    if (wasPermissionGiven) {
        FCM.getAPNSToken().then((apnsToken) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(apnsToken));
            console.log(apnsToken);
        });

        FCM.getToken().then((apnsToken) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(apnsToken));
            console.log(apnsToken);
        });

        FCM.subscribeToTopic('handsome');
        const disposables = FCM.onNotification((payload) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(payload.toString()));
            console.log('payload', payload);
        });
    }
});
```

By using the above code I am getting token and payload. Currently, I am populating the payload with a popup. can someone help me with implementing a notification instead of a popup? I searched a lot in google not found any references to implement notification with Cordova react.

Comment: If I believe I'm correct, then you need to push a notification to FCM, which will push it to the device.

Comment: @VijayDev do you have any sample snippet or reference link.

Comment: No, I have never implemented one myself. But it's easy to understand that FCM is the only way to push notifications. So to notify the users that the notification setup complete is to send one in via FCM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1: Testing app in Background State

Send the notification from firebase cloud messaging and test the APP in background state / minimise the app then you'll see the notification.

Case 2: Testing app in Foreground State

You should use some plugin something similar to this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#readme to get the firebase notifications While app is in foreground.

Comment: is it working? I am unable to use it. please give an example for this. thank you in advance.